# query results are not found in cache

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, caching, ehcache

Env: JBoss 5.1, ehcache 2.1.0, hibernate 3.3.x, seam 2.2.0

ehcache.xml (2.1.0 version) contains the following lines, but my query results are not found in cache. Am I supposed to set a cache region for each of the queries which are fired. What am I missing here?

```
<!-- Cache configuration -->
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="5000" eternal="true" timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I supposed to set a cache region for each of the queries which are fired. What am I missing here?

No you're not (unless you want a fine-grained control on them). Here is what the Documentation has to say on the topic:

> #### [19.4. The Query Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache)
>
> Query result sets can also be cached.
>   This is only useful for queries that
>   are run frequently with the same
>   parameters. You will first need to
>   enable the query cache:
>
> ```
> hibernate.cache.use_query_cache true
> ```
>
> This setting creates two new cache
>   regions: one holding cached query
>   result sets
>   (`org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache`),
>   the other holding timestamps of the
>   most recent updates to queryable
>   tables
>   (`org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache`).
>   **Note that the query cache does not
>   cache the state of the actual entities
>   in the result set; it caches only
>   identifier values and results of value
>   type. The query cache should always
>   be used in conjunction with the
>   second-level cache**.
>
> Most queries do not benefit from
>   caching, so by default, queries are
>   not cached. To enable caching, call
>   `Query.setCacheable(true)`. This call
>   allows the query to look for existing
>   cache results or add its results to
>   the cache when it is executed.
>
> If you require fine-grained control
>   over query cache expiration policies,
>   you can specify a named cache region
>   for a particular query by calling
>   `Query.setCacheRegion()`.
>
> ```
> List blogs = sess.createQuery("from Blog blog where blog.blogger = :blogger")
>     .setEntity("blogger", blogger)
>     .setMaxResults(15)
>     .setCacheable(true)
>     .setCacheRegion("frontpages")
>     .list();
> ```
>
> If the query should force a refresh of
>   its query cache region, you should
>   call
>   `Query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)`.
>   This is particularly useful in cases
>   where underlying data may have been
>   updated via a separate process (i.e.,
>   not modified through Hibernate) and
>   allows the application to selectively
>   refresh particular query result sets.
>   This is a more efficient alternative
>   to eviction of a query cache region
>   via `SessionFactory.evictQueries()`.

Now, the question are:

- did you enable the second level cache?
- did you enable the caching of the entities your query is about?
- do you actually enable caching of your query by calling `setCacheable(true)`?

This is unrelated but I also suggest to activate logging of the `org.hibernate.cache` category.

#### See also

- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Comment: I have enabled second level cache.
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"                value="${db.jpa.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
value="${db.jpa.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}"/>

@Cache annotations has been added to the entity classes
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

We use the EntityQuery framework and hence we set the setHints() method with cacheable flag set to true

I have enabled logging, hence I found out that the query results were not cached

Comment: @Samuel: That's the kind of "details" that would be worth mentioning in your question. It might help to get better answers (and readers would not waste their time).

Comment: I agree, should have done that as part of the question itself